# Would a bad limit switch cut power to the thermostat?

Tags: hvac

My Nest thermostat is not working and it says the red wire is not getting power. The gas company man poked around the furnace and thinks it is a bad limit switch.

Can a bad limit switch stop power from reaching the thermostat? If not, then can a bad pressure switch do the same thing? It would be easy to remove the pressure switch but the limit switch is inside a metal box.

Comment: Yes, can you post the wiring diagram for your furnace for that matter?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible depending on how your furnace controls are wired. Sometimes the limit switch will cut the 120V power supply to the 24V transformer that powers the thermostat, sometimes it's wired to cut the 24V power from the transformer to the thermostat, but you'd need to look at the schematic for your furnace and verify that the actual wiring follows the schematic. It's possible that it's been modified.

If the limit switch was tested bad, not just guessed bad, you are going to have to bite the bullet and replace it. It may be easier to test the limit switch than to trace out all the controls.